# Set default font size in styles.xml

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on an android project.

I have a tabbed page and the title of the pages are very big.
What i want to do is to decrease font size by changing values in styles.xml

do you know if it is possible ?

The project is written with Xamarin, so i want to avoid to write some specific code, like renderers.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12):

This is possible
**`styles.xml`** as follow:

```
 <style name="FontTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
 </style>
```

**use code:**

```
<TextView   
    style="@style/FontTheme"  
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"  
    android:text="test1"/>
```

Comment: I am working on Xamarin, i cannot set style on controls. Is there a way in styles.xml to define a default font size for each kind of UI Component ? Thanks