# How to change font size programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, font-size, android-styles, android-fonts

I need to change the font size of my application at runtime. I referred the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385047/6680585) where they speak about applying font size via styles.xml and applying it. I think it's applicable only for a particular element (like TextView or layout) but is it possible to apply the font size at application level and is it possible to set it programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the Font Size in a whole Application programmatically, Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704216/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-a-whole-application-programmatically-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, setting text size is :

```
textView.setTextSize(20)// text size
```

added few more things here :)

1.If you want to set as DP

```java
textView.setTextSize(coverPixelToDP(20));
    
private int coverPixelToDP (int dps) {
    final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dps * scale);
}
```

2.If you want to **adjust font size automatically** to fit boundaries use,

> setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(int
> autoSizeMinTextSize, int autoSizeMaxTextSize,
> int autoSizeStepGranularity, int unit)

JAVA Version

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Adjust font size for dynamic text");
//only works when width = 'match_parent', and give height
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500); 
           
textView.setLayoutParams(p1);
textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(8, 15, 1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP);
```

XML Version (Programatically)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent" // make sure it is match_parent
      android:layout_height="500dp" //make sure you give height 
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
      app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
      app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
      app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Take your text view `TextView textView` 
and apply `setTextSize(size)`

```
textView.setTextSize(20);
```

Note that size is in pixels, not `dp` as in styles.xml layout